# Servicestack - OrmLite query by date on SQLite32 database does not return any results

Tags: sqlite, datetime, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I ran into something strange today by query-ing an 32 bits SQLite embedded database using ServiceStack ORMLite *(Testing on Windows 2012 Server, .NET Framework 4.0).*

Consider the following test queries:

```
var dateMinimum = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_doNotProcessQueueItemWhenOlderThanHours);
using (var db = DbConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{
    var queueItemsTest1 = db.Select<ProcessQueue>(pc => (pc.Status == ProcessingStatus.Failed.ToString()) && (pc.DateCreated > dateMinimum)).ToList();
    var queueItemsTest2 = db.Select<ProcessQueue>(pc => (pc.Status == ProcessingStatus.Failed.ToString())).ToList();
    var queueItemsTest3 = db.Select<ProcessQueue>(pc => (pc.DateCreated > dateMinimum)).ToList();


    var queueItemsUnparsed = db.Select<ProcessQueue>().ToList();
    var queueItems = new List<ProcessQueue>();
    foreach (var queueItemUnparsed in queueItemsUnparsed)
    {
        if ((queueItemUnparsed.Status == ProcessingStatus.Failed.ToString()) && (queueItemUnparsed.DateCreated > dateMinimum))
        {
            queueItems.Add(queueItemUnparsed);
        }
    }
}

public class ProcessQueue
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

What is strange that:

- queueItemsTest1 returns nothing
- queueItemsTest2 returns all correct rows
- queueItemsTest3 returns nothing
- The `foreach` construction returns the correct rows.

Is there some way to log what is going on inside the database?

I think it is SQLite related because I have another queue which talks to SQL server and this works. I am using SQLite because this queue must be embedded and could not find a way to make ORMLite work with SQL Compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some way to log what is going on inside the database?

The simplest way is to use `Console.WriteLine(db.GetLastSql());`

So in your case:

```cs
var queueItemsTest1 = db.Select<ProcessQueue>(pc => (pc.Status == ProcessingStatus.Failed.ToString()) && (pc.DateCreated > dateMinimum)).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(db.GetLastSql());

var queueItemsTest2 = db.Select<ProcessQueue>(pc => (pc.Status == ProcessingStatus.Failed.ToString())).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(db.GetLastSql());

var queueItemsTest3 = db.Select<ProcessQueue>(pc => (pc.DateCreated > dateMinimum)).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(db.GetLastSql());
```

Then you should be able to use the SQL output to determine what query it is building. If I were to hazard a guess I would say it's to do with the Date handling.

---

You can't use the `DateTime` object because SQLite does not support a corresponding format.

From the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

Using `DateTime.Ticks` should provide an appropriate `long`.

Comment: I missed that statement, was thinking too complicated (using profilers or something). Thanks. If I run it I see (I removed the select columns): 
SELECT * 
FROM "ProcessQueue"
WHERE ("DateCreated" > '2014-01-22T10:56:50.7668626'). And now I see the 'T' is the problem (at least I think). If I replace the T with a space it returns data using 'SQLite Expert Professional'

Comment: According too a posting: the "T" appears literally in the string, to indicate the beginning of the time element, as specified in ISO 8601

Comment: @Stackbever So does your date work if you do `dateMinimum.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`?

Comment: When searching on the internet I see SQLite does not support a native DateTime format. Do I guess it is difficult to compare from C# using DateTime. I created now another solution: I have replaced it with a counter (int) which above a threshold stops processing the Queue Item.

Comment: @Stackbever You are right that SQLite doesn't support a DateTime format. I have updated the answer to make this clear for others. Storing the `DateTime.Ticks` may also be a useful way to store dates.

Comment: Really great help Scott (again and again). I should pay you for you help ;-)

Comment: @Stackbever Thanks, you're welcome. I think you got most of this on your own. I am sure it will be useful to others. :)